# Coding Polynomial Division

Tags: java, linked-list, polynomial-math

I'm trying to code the four basic operators for polynomials for a school assignment. I am currently stuck on the division portion. Wikipedia has a mock-up of the [pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#Example) but I can't really implement it into my code properly. Part of the assignment was also to use a LinkedList so each of my Polynomials is a LinkedList with Term objects containing a coefficient and exponent variable.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public void dividePolynomials(LinkedList<Term> a, LinkedList<Term> b)
{
    LinkedList<Term> q = new LinkedList<Term>;
    LinkedList<Term> r = a;

    while(!isEmpty(r) && (r.highestDegree() > d.highestDegree()))
    {
        int co = r.get(0).getCo()/d.get(0).getCo();
        int ex = r.get(0).getEx()/d.get(0).getEx();
        Term t = new Term();
    }
}
```

I tried to follow the Wikipedia pseudo code but obviously I didn't complete it. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: how is `Term` implemented ? Can you give me an example of input/output expected ?

Comment: The Term class has two parameters coefficient and exponent for example 2x^3 would be Term(2, 3). The input for this division method is two LinkedLists (a and b) and the output should be a divided by b. Using two polynomials that would not have a remainder the output should be another polynomial. With a remainder there would be a polynomial and a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following strictly to the pseudo-code, you'll see that  takes in two polynomials, and returns a new polynomial. This may not be consistent with your other operators, but is probably the best choice here. So your method header should be more along the lines of

`public QRPair dividePolynomials(LinkedList<Term> a, LinkedList<Term> b)`

where `QRPair` is a class consisting of two polynomials; a `quotient` and a `remainder`.

The following is a rough translation of the pseudocode.

```
public LinkedList<Term> deepCopy(LinkedList<Term> p)   {
    //implement this!
}
public QRPair dividePolynomials(LinkedList<Term> a, LinkedList<Term> b) {
    LinkedList<Term> q = "0"    //set q to be the polynomial 0
    LinkedList<Term> r = deepCopy(a);  //want a copy of a, not just reference.      
    while(!isEmpty(r) && (r.highestDegree() > d.highestDegree()))
    {
            int co = r.get(0).getCo()/d.get(0).getCo();
            int ex = r.get(0).getEx()/d.get(0).getEx();
            Term t = new Term(co,ex);
            q = addPolynomials(q,t);
            r = subtractPolynomials(r,multiplyPolynomials(t,d));
            //assume subtract/multiplyPolynomial returns LinkedList<Term>
    }
    return QRPair(q,r);
}
```

Note that you still have to implement `deepCopy`. The reason why we can't do the assignment `r = a` is because that means `r` and `a` would reference the same object, which we don't want. Similarly, if we do `r = (LinkedList<Term>)a.clone()`, then `r` would have a (shallow) copy of the linked list `a`. However, each element in `r` would reference the same object as each element in `a`, which is also not what we want. We want elements in `r` to be independent from elements of `a`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had to edit the code a bit to make it fit my program but it should work. Now I have some weird logic errors popping up in a different method I have to solve before I can check the division :)